# Problemas al integrar jQuery Validator con AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directivas

Tengo la siguiente directiva, que conseguí en la web para usar [jQuery Validator con Angularjs](https://github.com/jpkleemans/angular-validate)

```
app.directive('ngValidate', function () {
    return {
        require: 'form',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngValidate: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, form) {
            var validator = element.validate(scope.ngValidate);
            form.validate = function (options) {
                var oldSettings = validator.settings;
                validator.settings = $.extend(true, {}, validator.settings, options);
                var valid = validator.form();
                validator.settings = oldSettings; // Reset to old settings
                return valid;
            };

            form.numberOfInvalids = function () {
                return validator.numberOfInvalids();
            };
        }
    };
})

.provider('$validator', function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        onsubmit: false // to prevent validating twice
    });

    return {
        setDefaults: function (options) {
            $.validator.setDefaults(options);
        },
        addMethod: function (name, method, message) {
            $.validator.addMethod(name, method, message);
        },
        $get: function () {
            return {};
        }
    };
});
```

Esta lo que hace es que pueda validar un formulario usando Jquery Validate.

Mi Html

```
<form id="order-form" class="smart-form"   ng-submit="register(order-form)" ng-validate="validationOptions">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="submitme">
</form>
```

En mi controlador llamo de la siguiente forma

```
  $scope.register = function (form) {
    if(form.validate()) {
        // Form is valid!
        alert('hallo')
    }
  }
```

pero la linea del `if(form.validate())` me devuelve *form.validate is not a function*. Si veo la directiva se tiene el form.validate pero no entiendo porque me llega que no es una función. Mas aya de todo mis manejo con directivas no es muy avanzado. No se que puedo hacer para `form.validate` se ejecute.

Comment: porque necesitas de jquery validation para implementar validaciones en angular? lo pregunto porque esto no seria necesario, angular implementa su propia forma de validar controles que es aun mejor

Comment: He cambiado el título de la pregunta para que sea mas fácil de encontrarla, me parece un tema interesante y con dos buenas respuestas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No evaluaste hacer uso de las validaciones que impelmenta el propio angular.

Este cuenta con el $valid o $invalid, para conocer si el form esta correcto o no

[AngularJS Form Validation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation)

Es mas si lo unes a ngMessages puedes personalizar como mostrar los mensajes

[AngularJS Form Validation with ngMessages](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages)

A donde apunto es que la tecnica que brinda angular es mejor que la que podrias obtener con validaciones de jquery

Comment: Inicialmente lo tenia solo con las validaciones e iba a colocar los messages, pero el cliente solicito usar jquery dataTable, creo que haré unas pruebas, pero igual no logro comprender porque `form` nunca es visto.  Creo que según la [documentación](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom)  el no permite ningún parámetro `from`

Comment: El tema es que form es un elemento del html, por lo tanto desde los controller o service no tiene acceso al mismo. Es mas si analzias las validaciones del propio angular en los articulos que sugiero, veras que el $valid o $error se genera desde la view, es porque estos tambien usan el form, pero desde el html. Quizas si le pasas desde el html la instancia del form al controller podrias acceder a este

Comment: + 1 Me quede con este enfoque, solo le coloque los ngMessages y listo. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta en como usas ngSubmit; ya que esta espera una *[expresion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit#usage)*:

```
<form ng-submit="expresion">
```

Como estas utilizando: `ng-submit="register(order-form)"` angular entiende esto como: order menos form.

Solución: no utilizes operadores en el nombre. Por Ejemplo cámbialo a: *orderform*

Ademas, el ejemplo que hay en la [documentacion](https://github.com/jpkleemans/angular-validate#set-validation-options) utiliza la propiedad `name` en lugar de `id` para el nombre del form, quedaria asi:

```
<form name="orderform" class="smart-form" ng-submit="register(orderform)" ng-validate="validationOptions">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="submitme">
</form>
```

Comment: +1 aunque tienes toda la razón, no lo haré con esas validaciones, los problemas que me estaba dando eran mayores. Gracias por tu ayuda.